# DIV page break (not printing)

Tags: html, css, layout, page-break

Probably a simple question, but what's the best way to use a div to logically break up a page, vertically, regardless of how the items above and below it are floated or positioned.  For viewing on the web, not page break in terms of printing.

I am trying something like this but it is not working:

```
<div id="top block" style="width: margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; clear: both">
<div id="left" style="float: left; width: 200px">
<p>Text text text</p>
</div>
<div id="center" style="float: left; width: 500px;">
Image
</div>
<div id="right" style="float: left; width: 200px">
<p>Text text text</p>
</div>
</div> <!--End of top block-->

<div id="page break" style="width: 1000px; clear: both;"></div> <!--I want this to be a hard break where everything after it appears below-->

<div id="bottom block" style="text-align: center">
<p>Text text text</p>  <!--Things from this paragraph are popping up above the forced page break depending on how I align things.-->
</div>
```

Comment: I put all of my code inside of <pre> but it is not showing up, if someone could edit it that would be fantastic

Comment: What seems to be going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/m7ZZE/

Comment: Typo in the first line: `width: margin-left: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

i do not encounter your problem. By the way you dont need to specify a width to your "break" div, you can try with:

```
<div id="page break" style="clear: both; display:block;"></div>
```

[here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcxFz/) where i colored the div to let you see better his behavior.